# L shape corner floating shelves

Tags: shelf

I'm trying to build as thin shelves as possible in a corner of a room, in a L shape. Approx 1.3m x 1.2m. One wall is an alcove so can easily put battens in there and build a frame/tension box/etc with a cover and bottom. They will be slit 280mm deep.

Struggling to see if the wall without the alcove will have enough support at the front of the unsupported side.

And ideally I don't want to build super thick shelves but I'm open to options...

I've had one suggestion which is to put 12mm steel rods and chemical anchors into the shelves but various videos suggest the shelf would move end up wobbling a bit as a result (up and down)

I guess I could do battens and rods. Any other suggestions?

I have about 5-6 shelves to do in the same corner.

[image: sketch of shelves]

(Sorry on a mobile so not the best drawing. The area I'm concerned about is marked by the blue arrow. E.g. there's only the wall support opposite there.

Thanks.

Comment: Pictures and/or drawing of what you're trying to do will go kilometers beyond what your words have done to describe the situation. Please make a neat drawing (doesn't have to be to scale), labeling things and showing dimensions, then [edit] you question and add the drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sketch of a similar shelf I made (a long time ago):
[image]
The frame was made with nominal 2 x 1s. The top and bottom were covered with 1/4" hardboard (the top is not shown). I secured nominal 2 x 2s on the wall by screwing them into the studs. Then, I slid the shelf on and secured it with a few screws through the top into the 2 x 2s attached to the wall.

I don't know the maximum weight that it could hold, but it was sturdy, and I was never concerned with what I put on it, like books.